# Proving that a graph is a planar graph

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I looked at some problems where I had to prove that a graph is a planar graph. What methods are there to do this?

For example:

Is there a 4-regular graph with 16 vertexes which is a planar graph?

Comment: I dont think it has be planar. Take for instance $K_5$, which is not planar, and a graph with $11$ vertices that is $4$ regular. Together they have $16$ vertices and every degree is $4$, but since $K_5$ is not planar, then our constructed graph is not planar. I am using without proof that there is a graph on $11$ vertices that is $4$ regular, which according to the above link exists.

Comment: @DanielMontealegre 4-regular graphs are easy to construct for any size ($\geq 5$ vertices): put all the vertices in a loop and connect two forward and two backward.

Comment: The tesseract graph is a non-planar, 4-regular graph with 16 vertices.

Answer (score 5):

There are two general ways:

- show an embedding into $\mathbb{R}^2$, hence graph is planar,
- show it contains $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ as a minor, thus graph is not planar.

In your case you could use the following feature to construct a graph with an embedding (this only shows that there exists a 4-regular planar graph):

[image: planar]

Also, it's not hard to construct a non-planar 4-regular graph, e.g.

[image]

The red part is $K_{3,3}$ while blue edges make the graph connected (otherwise the graph is 3-regular).

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: @user76508 consider accepting this answer as an accepted one if it answered your question